# Why are we advised to put an ice pack on a swelling?

Tags: swelling

The idea behind it is that the ice pack reduces blood flow to the injury, but why is that a good thing? Shouldn't we leave this fundamental type of injury to mother nature to deal with, as our ancestors have done for hundreds of millions of years?

Comment: Hi Lost, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Ice pack vs. heat packs does depend on the cause of the swelling, from my understanding. As @IanCampbell has asked, what have you found online regarding this?